# My external hard drive has a 360 GB system file

Tags: windows

I have a 2 TB external hard drive. Inside the Windows hidden folder "Systeme Volume Information", there is a 360 GB system file. What can it be ?

I also noticed the other day when I tried to back up my computer that Windows considers this external hard drive as a system drive, and I can't unselect it while backing up (I'm forced to unplug it to back up only my real system drive).

Here is the file : [image]

And here is Windows preventing me to back up if I don't include that external hard drive : [image]

Could it be related to File History ? How to make sure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in fact not a file but a [Shadow Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), typically created by System Restore on regular intervals and certain events.

Shadow Copies are atomic filesystem snapshots. You can list existing Shadow Copies using the `vssadmin` tool:

```
vssadmin list shadows
```

You can also delete these snapshots, although I’m not sure whether this functionality has always been present on consumer versions of Windows. Windows 8.1 Update 1 at least can do it:

```
vssadmin delete shadows /for=X:
```

...where X: is the drive you want to work on.